# Serialise/Deserialise class with abstract base class loses value

Tags: c#, serialization, abstract-class, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Given an abstract base class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class UserSubmission : EntityObj
{
    [ProtoMember(51)]
    public int AuthorID { get; protected set; }
}
```

And an inheriting class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public partial class PrivateMessage : UserSubmission
{
    [ProtoMember(1000)]
    private int ToUserID { get; set; }

    ...
```

When I serialise/deserialise a `PrivateMessage` the `AuthorID` property is reset to default (`0`) when it should show a different value.

Am I doing anything wrong, or misunderstand how ProtoBuff.net works here?

Comment: you need to use `ProtoInclude` on the base class: `[ProtoInclude(999, typeof(PrivateMessage))]`.  which seems backwards to me

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the answer, I have multiple inheritance and am playing round with what you suggest but am not sure exactly where to put `ProtoInclude`, on `EntityObj` or `UserSubmission`?  Both seem to return `0` still.

Comment: [This answer has an article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12989068/1070452) link which is interesting.  If there is relevant Entiry stuff I *think* you'd have to include UserSubmission  and PrivateMessage

Comment: @Plutonix great thanks this works!  I was getting confused as was defining all child classes in base class, when you should only protoinclude the direct children in each level.

Comment: @Plutonix if you want to put it into an answer happy to mark as correct!

Comment: Since there is already a good answer here (the link above), I'd just dupe-close to that.  (I think I used that the first time *I* ran into the issue)