# Serializing Unknown Sub-Types With Protobuf-Net

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to get my head around protobuf-net at the moment, and found this article on being able to serialize sub-types: [How to Serialize Inherited Class with ProtoBuf-Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988964/how-to-serialize-inherited-class-with-protobuf-net)

Effectively this suggests that the base type needs to know about the sub-type:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(SubType))]
class BaseType { ... }

class SubType : BaseType { ... }
```

Questions:

1. What if the sub-type is unknown?
2. Can protobuf-net be automatically configured for a particular type and its sub-types (without knowing them)?
3. Thirdly, is there something like a Fluent-API for configuring protobuf-net, instead of using attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3. Yes, there is a full API for this under RuntimeTypeModel, including callbacks for auto-discovery during runtime rather than ahead of time

However!

No, it can't work with unknown subtypes unless you mean: by ignoring the subtype aspect completely and just treating it as though it were the known type.

Comment: Thanks Marc! Could you point me in the right direction for some documentation on this, please?

Comment: @Matthew I'm not sure I've ever written longform documentation on that aspect. The API and examples are there. Is there something specific you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically, I'm building something that auto-configures all sub-types for serialization based on a convention that it will serialize all public instance properties of those sub-types. I've also tweeted you something in relation to this and record types.

Comment: I've forked the protobuf-net repo so I'll do some digging :-)

Comment: What about ProtoContract(IgnoreUnknownSubTypes = true) tag is it usefull in this case?