# Serialization of base class properties with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We have a somewhat complex hierarchy of classes in our entity model. We have a base class `BaseEntity` for all entities, then some "level 2" classes derived from `BaseEntity`, some "level 3" classes derived from any "level 2" class, and a lot of "level 4" classes, derived from any "level 3" class. That means, we have something like this:

- BaseEntity

  - DerivedEntity_1

    - DerivedEntity_1_1

      - DerivedEntity_1_1_1
      - DerivedEntity_1_1_2
      - DerivedEntity_1_1_3
    - DerivedEntity_1_2

      - DerivedEntity_1_2_1
      - DerivedEntity_1_2_2
  - DerivedEntity_2

    - DerivedEntity_2_1

      - DerivedEntity_2_1_1
    - DerivedEntity_2_2

      - DerivedEntity_2_2_1
      - DerivedEntity_2_2_2
      - DerivedEntity_2_2_3
      - DerivedEntity_2_2_4

And so on and so forth...

Now, when transferring instances of these types via WCF using protobuf-net, only the properties of the "level 4" classes are transferred - all properties from the base classes are lost!

From several other StackOverflow threads ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505471/protobuf-net-deserialize-base-class-to-inherited-class), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109868/protobuf-net-base-class-properties-is-not-included-when-serializing-derived-clas), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530787/serialize-inherited-classes-using-protobuf-net)), I read that this is the default behavior and that you have two options to work around it:

1. Use the `[ProtoInclude]` attribute on the base class.
2. Configure the inheritance at runtime using a `TypeModel` and `AddSubType()`.

However, none of these options are feasible in our scenario since we have a lot of derived classes. Option 1 would mean hundreds of attributes on the level 1 base class. Option 2 would mean a lot of calls to `AddSubType()`.

**Are there any other options?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it needs to understand how it should store the data, so that you can get it back. It can't just guess... So: the only robust way to do that is to define the model somewhere. That doesn't have to be in raw code, though: for example, maybe it could be stored in an external file that you include and process (via AddSubType) at runtime.

Comment: But how does the default WCF serializer do that? It works perfectly with that one. (Well, except that it is slow...) Can't we use the same strategy with protobuf as well?

Comment: @gehho `DataContractSerializer` has the luxury of including lots of verbose naming via elements etc, which gives it a decent stab at understanding things. The protobuf specification *does not have room for that*. You just get extremely terse field identifiers (integers). There is no mechanism I can think of that would allow we to understand that `12` means `DerivedEntity_2_2_3`, without risking major problems when the code is edited in any way (for example, somebody adds `Derived_Entity_2_2_1b`).

Comment: @gehho More recently, there is some support (protobuf-net only) for dynamic typing via embedding type information in the stream, but that does *not* currently play well with inheritance, and is intended for flat models only. Well, I *intend* it for more complex models, but there is some grunt-work required to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies! OK, I understand the problem. I will see if it is possible to generate the required code using the T4 template that we use to generate the entity classes. I just hoped there might be an easier solution...